# How to center input radio

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, fieldset

I'm using jquery mobile for my project. It automatically converts all radio buttons in its inputs with its styles. The major problem is that in different situations i have different number of buttons (it depends on user) with its different width and i need it every time center.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="inline" >
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        {section name=i loop=$data['input'] start=0}
            <input name="position" id="radio{$smarty.section.i.index}" value="{$data['input'][i]}" type="radio" />
            <label for="radio{$smarty.section.i.index}">
                {$data['input'][i]}
            </label>
        {/section}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

[image: buttons]

As you see each button has his size (for example Up and Zoom In are different). As i said before - i don't know what buttons will be for each users - it depends on their own settings, so i need somehow automatize process of centering it - is some ideas?

Comment: If it's a block maybe you could center it with css `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto`? [Source](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

Comment: Or you could try it with `<a>` instead of `<input>` as done in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html), if at all possible in your situation.

Comment: @Calavoow oh man, thanks a lot!!! With a deadline I had forgotten the existence of simple buttons

Comment: Turned into an answer then, good luck with your deadline.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with `<a>` instead of `<input>` as done in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html), if at all possible in your situation.